# Show that $\int\limits_{C_R} Q(z) \to 0$ as $R \to \infty$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a_1, ... , a_N \in \mathbb{C}$ be distinct, $N \geq 4$ and $$Q(z) = \frac{z^2}{(z-a_1) \cdots (z - a_N)}$$ Assume the $a_i$ are contained in a circle about the origin of radius $R_0$, and let $C_R$ be a circle oriented counterclockwise of center $0$ and radius $R > R_0$.  The problem I have is to show that $$\int\limits_{C_R} Q(z) \to 0$$ as $R \to \infty$.  If I'm not mistaken, that integral does not change for $R > R_0$, and is equal to $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues at $a_1, ... , a_N$.  If $a_k = 0$, then the singularity at $a_k$ is removable, and the residue is $0$.  If $a_k \neq 0$, and we let $g(z) = (z-a_1) \cdots (z- a_N)$, then $Q(z)$ has a simple pole at $a_k$, meaning the residue at $a_k$ can be calculated as $$\lim\limits_{z \to a_k} Q(z)(z-a_k) = \frac{a_k^2}{g'(a_k)}$$ The same formula works when $a_k = 0$.  So, the problem is asserting that $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^N \frac{a_k^2}{g'(a_k)} = 0$$ Is this really true?

Comment: This can be done much more easily by a direct estimation.For  $z \in C_R$, you can estimate $|Q(z)| \le const. \cdot R^{2-N}$ for a suitable constant. And the length of $C_R$ is $2 \pi R$. Where does that get you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the Cauchy estimate.

> $$\left|\int_{C_R}Q(z)\,dz\right|\le 2\pi R\cdot \max_{z\in C_R}\left|{z^2\over 
> (z-a_1)\ldots (z-a_N)}\right|<\!<{2\pi R^3\over R^4}=2\pi R^{-1}\stackrel{R\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0.$$

since $N\ge 4$.